How to apply OLS with constraints on coefficients and align the output scale with the target variable?
I am working on an OLS regression problem where:
The dependent variable (target) ranges from 1 to 6 (with steps of 1).
The independent variables range from 1 to 10 (with steps of 0.5).
I want to set up the model such that:
There is no intercept.
The sum of all coefficients (β) is equal to 1.
The output aligns with the scale of the dependent variable (1 to 6).
However, when all independent variables are at their maximum value of 10, the model output scales up to 10, which is outside the target range. I can't scale the independent variables. I can scale the depended variables. So, that it is 1 to 10. Below is the mapping I have used to scale dependent variable.



original Scale
New scale




1
1


2
2.8


3
4.6


4
6.4


5
8.2


6
10



But is there any other way? How can I adjust my OLS setup?
I’d appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to implement this.

This might be do-able, but it would not be OLS anymore. Also, I suggest that you use ordinal logistic regression with an output variable like yours. Also, scaling the output to a number that is impossible seems like a bad idea. //  Maybe you have reasons for all this; if you do, please edit your question to include them. But, as is, I think you are asking for help to do the wrong analysis.

I have added the scale mapping. Yes, I will look at ordinal model. But I will prefer OLS if do able.

It's definitely not OLS.  Not with that DV and all those conditions.

Could you please explain what you mean by "aligns with" and "scales up to"?

Currently, I am trying orderedModel and want to confirm that I can train the model on training data  and then use training params to calculate loglikelihood of validation data like this  val_model = OrderedModel(y_val, X_val, distr='logit')         val_log_likelihood = val_model.loglike(result.params)      here, I have just initialized the orderedModel on validation but have not fit it and using result.params from fitting the model on training data. I want to do this to calculate out of sample LL.

That's a baffling comment because it appears unrelated to the questions in your post!

@whuber, I just posted it as Peter Flom suggested to use Ordinal Logistic regression.
